# Why does append overwrite the list?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I was trying some questions from hackerrank and came across this question
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/list-comprehensions/problem

I tried this solution

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
n = int(input())
L = []
SL = []
for i in range(0, x + 1):
    for j in range(0, y + 1):
        for k in range(0, z + 1):
            if i + j + k != n:
                SL[:] = []
                SL.append(i)
                SL.append(j)
                SL.append(k)
                print(SL)
                L.append(SL)
print(L)
```

although SL had the right solution I can't append SL to the main list L for some reason, and apparently L.append(SL) overwrites the list L each time it it executed as it prints the last value of SL.
Why does it happen?
I tried using extend, but instead of making it a list of lists, it was created as just a list of integers.
EDIT: Thank you all for the explanations!

Comment: I tried extend, but instead of making it a list of lists, it was created as just a list of integers.

Comment: Apparently it works correctly on my side. Can you give an example of what you observe and the difference with your expected output ?

Comment: Did not run your code, but this looks suspicious `SL[:] = []`. Try to create a new list each time: `SL = []`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/XwCtLzL
This was the problem occurring, I printed SL before appending it to L.

Comment: thanks @VPfB , that seems to have done the trick, any idea how?

Comment: It creates a new list instead of reusing the old one.

Comment: @loksoni I posted an answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed your code does not work, and it is due to the line `SL[:] = []`: it changes the content of the list referenced by `SL`. By doing this, you change all the elements of `L`, because you always append the list referenced by `SL` to `L` in the loop. Replacing with `SL = []` will fix the problem, because in this case you create a new list without overwriting the previous one.
It could be fixed, and also be more readable and easier to debug (if needed) with the following suggestion:

```
L = []
for i in range(0, x + 1):
    for j in range(0, y + 1):
        for k in range(0, z + 1):
            if i + j != n and i + k != n and k + j != n and i + j + k != n:
                L.append([i, j, k])
print(L)
```

With x=1, y=2, z=3, n=4: it gives me the following output:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 3], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 0], 
 [0, 2, 1], [0, 2, 3], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 1, 0],  [1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 0]]
```

Comment: yes, that seems to be it, thanks for the suggestion, pretty cool! What do you think was the problem?

Comment: I added explanation for your original problem.

Comment: You could reduce that loop nesting with `itertools.product`. Like this: `for i, j, k in product(range(x+1), range(y+1), range(z+1)):`

Answer (score 1):

This line clears the list by deleting all its items. The list stays the same variable (same object), only its contents is modified:

```
SL[:] = []
```

Later in the code is this line (in a loop):

```
L.append(SL)
```

But SL is the same variable each time. All items in `L` refer to the same list `SL`. So when `SL` is modified, all items in `L` refer to the new contents of `SL`.

This can be fixed by creating a new list for each result.